# Multiple librarys include functions with the same name

Tags: python, pandas, io, pycharm

I am working on a program in python that uses both the pandas and io library's and I am running into a issue with `image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imageData))` where the io.BytesIO is trying to be used as pandas.io instead of the .BytesIO function from the io library. This leads me to ask if their is a way to change witch function corresponds to this line. I am working in pyCharm 2022.1.4.

Comment: Post [mre] of your code. Did you by any chance use  star import (i.e. `from some_module import *`)? Probably `from pandas import *`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported the io package as ior

```
import io as ior
```

then just changed io.BytesIO to ior.BytesIO

Comment: If this is your "solution" - it's not OK. It may work for this particular use, but you probably shadowed way more names